# PostgreSQL - How to extract value in Json Column with Multiple dict

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{'0': {'action': ['SEARCH'], 'action_detail': {'SEARCH': 3}, 'total': 3},
 '16': {'action': ['SEARCH', 'ADD_TO_CART', 'SKU_DETAIL_VIEW'],
  'action_detail': {'ADD_TO_CART': 5, 'SEARCH': 6, 'SKU_DETAIL_VIEW': 4},
  'total': 15},
 '17': {'action': ['SEARCH',
   'SKU_DETAIL_VIEW',
   'CART_DETAIL',
   'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
   'QUICK_ORDER',
   'ADD_TO_CART'],
  'action_detail': {'ADD_TO_CART': 3,
   'CART_DETAIL': 2,
   'QUICK_ORDER': 2,
   'REMOVE_FROM_CART': 2,
   'SEARCH': 15,
   'SKU_DETAIL_VIEW': 6},
  'total': 30},
 '18': {'action': ['SKU_DETAIL_VIEW',
   'SEARCH',
   'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
   'QUICK_ORDER'],
  'action_detail': {'QUICK_ORDER': 1,
   'REMOVE_FROM_CART': 1,
   'SEARCH': 5,
   'SKU_DETAIL_VIEW': 2},
  'total': 9}
 '19': {'action': ['ADD_TO_CART'],
  'action_detail': {'ADD_TO_CART': 1},
  'total': 1},
 '6': {'action': ['ADD_TO_CART', 'SEARCH'],
  'action_detail': {'ADD_TO_CART': 1, 'SEARCH': 1},
  'total': 2}}
```

I have a column named 'event_tracking' within the value that looks like the above. I want to extract values in 'action_detail' into 3 columns with the rule ignore the value with key = 0, by using Postgresql query.

My expected result is

[image]

Any idea for my case?

Tks for all attentions <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a Common Table Expression (CTE), you can get the output you're looking for:

```
create table foo (j jsonb);

insert into foo values ('
{"0": {"action": ["SEARCH"], "action_detail": {"SEARCH": 3}, "total": 3},
 "16": {"action": ["SEARCH", "ADD_TO_CART", "SKU_DETAIL_VIEW"],
  "action_detail": {"ADD_TO_CART": 5, "SEARCH": 6, "SKU_DETAIL_VIEW": 4},
  "total": 15},
 "17": {"action": ["SEARCH",
   "SKU_DETAIL_VIEW",
   "CART_DETAIL",
   "REMOVE_FROM_CART",
   "QUICK_ORDER",
   "ADD_TO_CART"],
  "action_detail": {"ADD_TO_CART": 3,
   "CART_DETAIL": 2,
   "QUICK_ORDER": 2,
   "REMOVE_FROM_CART": 2,
   "SEARCH": 15,
   "SKU_DETAIL_VIEW": 6},
  "total": 30},
 "18": {"action": ["SKU_DETAIL_VIEW",
   "SEARCH",
   "REMOVE_FROM_CART",
   "QUICK_ORDER"],
  "action_detail": {"QUICK_ORDER": 1,
   "REMOVE_FROM_CART": 1,
   "SEARCH": 5,
   "SKU_DETAIL_VIEW": 2},
  "total": 9},
 "19": {"action": ["ADD_TO_CART"],
  "action_detail": {"ADD_TO_CART": 1},
  "total": 1},
 "6": {"action": ["ADD_TO_CART", "SEARCH"],
  "action_detail": {"ADD_TO_CART": 1, "SEARCH": 1},
  "total": 2}}
');


WITH a AS (
    SELECT key, jsonb_each(value->'action_detail') AS v
      FROM jsonb_each((SELECT j FROM foo))
    )
SELECT a.key, (a.v).*
FROM a;
 key |       key        | value 
-----+------------------+-------
 0   | SEARCH           | 3
 6   | SEARCH           | 1
 6   | ADD_TO_CART      | 1
 16  | SEARCH           | 6
 16  | ADD_TO_CART      | 5
 16  | SKU_DETAIL_VIEW  | 4
 17  | SEARCH           | 15
 17  | ADD_TO_CART      | 3
 17  | CART_DETAIL      | 2
 17  | QUICK_ORDER      | 2
 17  | SKU_DETAIL_VIEW  | 6
 17  | REMOVE_FROM_CART | 2
 18  | SEARCH           | 5
 18  | QUICK_ORDER      | 1
 18  | SKU_DETAIL_VIEW  | 2
 18  | REMOVE_FROM_CART | 1
 19  | ADD_TO_CART      | 1
(17 rows)
```

Comment: It works for my case. Many thanks, @richyen